# Sub-menu some ao tirar mouse Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e quando eu passo o mouse por cima do Entre/Cadastre-se ele me mostra um submenu
 com alguns links, mas quando eu vou ate um dos links do submenu,o submenu desaparece, como posso resolver esse problema ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".col-xs-3.col-md-3 .entre").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".conteudo_dropdow").show();
  });

  $(".conteudo_dropdow").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(".conteudo_dropdow").hide();
  });



});
```

```css
.conteudo_dropdow {
  display: none;
}

.conteudo_dropdow {
  margin-top: 38px;
  left: 0;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
  <h4 class="entre">Entre/Cadastre-se</h4>
</div>

<div class="conteudo_dropdow">

  <ul class="caixa">
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li><a href="#">Meus Pedidos</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Efetuar Login</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Alterar Dados</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Eita, foi mal, tinha esquecido de ver isso na outra pergunta... mas foi bom vc fazer outra pergunta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já havia respondido algo semelhante **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249602/8063)**:

> `mouseout` é acionado quando o cursor sai de qualquer elemento-filho e
>   do próprio elemento. Já o `mouseleave` só é acionado quando o cursor sai
>   do elemento todo.

Então, basta trocar o `mouseout` por `mouseleave`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".col-xs-3.col-md-3 .entre").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".conteudo_dropdow").show();
  });

  $(".conteudo_dropdow").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".conteudo_dropdow").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.conteudo_dropdow {
  display: none;
}

.conteudo_dropdow {
  margin-top: 38px;
  left: 0;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
  <h4 class="entre">Entre/Cadastre-se</h4>
</div>

<div class="conteudo_dropdow">

  <ul class="caixa">
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li><a href="#">Meus Pedidos</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Efetuar Login</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Alterar Dados</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde. Primeiro, eu acho desnecessário o uso do Javascript para uma aplicação como essa, ela pode ser resolvida apenas com CSS.

O que eu fiz foi passar a parte do menu que você deseja aparecer para dentro do "header", e criando uma classe "MENU" para o mesmo.

No CSS indiquei que, quando o menu estiver sob a propriedade [:hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp), deve aparecer, setando seu display para "block".

Dessa forma fica melhor estruturando não tendo que quebrar o menu em varias partes.

```css
 .conteudo_dropdow {
  display: none;
}

.conteudo_dropdow {
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu:hover .conteudo_dropdow{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 menu">
  <h4 class="entre">Entre/Cadastre-se</h4>
  <div class="conteudo_dropdow">

  <ul class="caixa">
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li><a href="#">Meus Pedidos</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Efetuar Login</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Alterar Dados</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo">
      <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Sair</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```